# How do I install OpenNI, OpenNI2 and Freenect in ROS Hydro?

Tags: openni, freenect, rosinstall, rtabmap, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS, and I have been trying to install the ros version of [rtabmap](https://code.google.com/p/rtabmap/wiki/Installation#ROS_version). Everything has gone fine, but when trying to interface with a kinect sensor I am required to install the OpenNI, OpenNI2 and Freenect packages. I know that ros has a utility called rosinstall, but I am confused about exactly WHICH packages to install using rosinstall - can anyone give me a hand with this? A bit of a simple question, sorry.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195656/how-do-i-install-openni,-openni2-and-freenect-in-ros-hydro?/) by [SheerSt](https://answers.ros.org/users/20553/sheerst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should have a look at these links ([freenect_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_camera), [openni_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera), [freenect_stack](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_stack)). You can `apt-get install` these packages directly if you have a debian Hydro already installed. alternatively you can also `clone and build` each package in your `catkin workspace` and source the `devel/setup.bash` to work with these packages.

For. eg:

> mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src

> cd  ~/catkin_ws/src

> git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera.git

> cd ..

> catkin_make

> source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

and finally you can do

> roscd openni_camera

to check if your ROS is able to see this package or not. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) with karma: 246 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SheerSt](https://answers.ros.org/users/20553/sheerst/) on 2014-10-24**:
Thanks, this was super helpful. I ended up doing the apt-get install, but I was hoping to just install it to my workspace. I tried everything you listed above, but instead of using the individual packages I cloned the freenect stack git (it didn't work). Also - what does `roscd openni_camera` do?

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2014-10-25**:
may be you have not installed the `git` in your pc you can try `sudo apt-get install git` first and then try the above steps. `roscd` is the ros implementation of the `linux cd` (a.k.a. change directory command) which is used to navigate to the `ros packages` in your pc.